# MatLab - Cellfun where func = strcmp Find where str changes in a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array, strcmp

I have a cell array of strings, I want to detect the num of times the string changes and get the indxs for the changes.  Given Matlab's cellfun function, I am trying to use it instead of looping.  Here is all the code.  I appreciate you time, feedback, and comments.

```
% Cell Array Example
names(1:10)={'OFF'};
names(11:15)={'J1 - 1'};
names(16:22)={'J1 - 2'};
names(23:27)={'J2 - 1'};
names(28)={'Off'};
names=names';

% My cellfun code
cellfun(@(x,y) strcmp(x,y), names(1:2:end),names(2:2:end));
```

My expected result is a vector of length 27 (length(names)-1), where there are 4 zeros in the vector indicating the strcmp func found 4 cases where the comparison was not equal.

The actual result is a vector of length 14 and has only 2 zeros.  I'd really appreciate an explanation, why this unexpected result is occurring.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687627/1292374) provided by Matt correctly shows the issue with your code. However, you can use [strcmp](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) directly because it accepts two cell array of strings as input

```
>> strcmp(names(1:end-1), names(2:end))
ans =
  Columns 1 through 14
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
  Columns 15 through 27
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a better solution

Answer (score 2):

You could transform the strings into numeric labels using [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), and then apply [`diff`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to detect changes:

```
[~, ~, u] = unique(names);
result = ~diff(u);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be comparing `names(1:end-1)` with `names(2:end)`.  That is, compare string 1 with string 2, compare string 2 with string 3, and so on.  You are instead using a stride of 2, comparing string 1 with string 2, string 3 with string 4, and so on.  You can fix this by changing your last line to:

```
cellfun(@(x,y) strcmp(x,y), names(1:end-1),names(2:end))
```

The result is then:

```
 Columns 1 through 20:

 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1

 Columns 21 through 27:

 1   0   1   1   1   1   0
```